# Testing a SiteLoginController Login method

Tags: unit-test, login

I am trying to write a unit test for a custom `SiteLoginController.Login()` method. The method is:

```
public PageReference login() {
    readUsernameCookie();
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    PageReference pr = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

    if (pr != null && rememberUsername == true){            
        boolean exists = false;
        for(string savedUsername : savedUsernames){
            if (savedUsername == username){
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!exists){
            savedUsernames.add(username);
        }
    }
    writeUsernameCookie(); // write cookie to maintain 1 week rolling expiry
    return pr;
}
```

I have the following methods set up to set up, execute and verify that the method redirects correctly.

```
public with sharing class GP_SiteLoginControllerBdd extends GP_BDD {
    private PageReference redirectToPage;

    public void GivenThereIsAUserAccount(){
        ID userId = this.GivenStandardUserExists();
        System.debug(userId);
    }

    public void WhenAUserLogsIn(){
        GP_SiteLoginController controller = new GP_SiteLoginController();
        controller.username = this.standardUser.Username;
        controller.password = 'testpwd';
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('www.mydomain.com/login/');
        pr.getParameters().put('startURL', 'myUrl');
        Test.setCurrentPage(pr);
        Test.startTest();
        redirectToPage = controller.login();
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    public void ThenAValidPageReferenceShouldBeReturned(){
        System.assertNotEquals(null, redirectToPage, 'redirectToPage is  null');
        System.assertEquals('myUrl', redirectToPage.getUrl());
    }
}
```

I need to create a test user with a known password to make this work. In the method `GivenStandardUserExists()`, I call the `Site.CreatePortalUser(user, accountId, password, sendEmail)` method, but it always returns a null ID, suggesting that hasn't worked. Further, in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) for the method, it says:

> This method is only valid when a site is associated with a Customer Portal.

Does that mean the method cannot be used in a unit test? How else can I create a user with a known password for use in a unit test?

Comment: Since you can't set a `Site` in a test class/method the only thing you can do is assert this is `null`. See the test class example at the top of the documentation you linked.